# vectorize pandas apply for pd.date_range

Tags: pandas, numpy

Any tricks to vectorize `apply` to `pd.date_range` ? It takes ages to compute for a few million rows.

```
df.columns=['id', 'date']


df['dates'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['date']- pd.Timedelta(days=14), row['date'], freq='D'), axis=1)
```

Comment: can you elaborate on why you need a `pd.date_range`?

Comment: @SchwarzeHuhn having start and finish for each row I want to get date_range for each row to `explode` afterwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a db similar to yours

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 100
u = [int(1349720105+x*10**7) for x in np.random.randn(n)]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'u': u,
    'date': pd.to_datetime(u, unit='s').date
})

df
             u        date
0   1345248819  2012-08-18
1   1361965182  2013-02-27
2   1353755021  2012-11-24
3   1355655890  2012-12-16
4   1338770986  2012-06-04
..         ...         ...
95  1333445721  2012-04-03
96  1355743297  2012-12-17
97  1353922927  2012-11-26
98  1357829621  2013-01-10
99  1360164525  2013-02-06
```

then repeat each 14 times

```
df_exp = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(14))
df_exp.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_exp['rn'] = df_exp.sort_values(['u'], ascending=[True]) \
             .groupby(['u']) \
             .cumcount()
df_exp_sort = df_exp.sort_values(['u', 'rn'], ascending=[True, True])
df_exp_sort

      index           u        date  rn
721      51  1325371727  2011-12-31   0
718      51  1325371727  2011-12-31   1
722      51  1325371727  2011-12-31   2
723      51  1325371727  2011-12-31   3
724      51  1325371727  2011-12-31   4
...     ...         ...         ...  ..
1009     72  1375003362  2013-07-28   9
1008     72  1375003362  2013-07-28  10
1021     72  1375003362  2013-07-28  11
1013     72  1375003362  2013-07-28  12
1020     72  1375003362  2013-07-28  13
```

now add date2

```
df_final = df_exp_sort
df_final['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(
    (df_final['date'].astype('datetime64[s]').astype('int') / 1e9).astype('int') + df_final['rn']*24*60*60, 
    unit='s'
).dt.date
df_final.head(20)

     index           u        date  rn       date2
721     51  1325371727  2011-12-31   0  2011-12-31
718     51  1325371727  2011-12-31   1  2012-01-01
722     51  1325371727  2011-12-31   2  2012-01-02
723     51  1325371727  2011-12-31   3  2012-01-03
724     51  1325371727  2011-12-31   4  2012-01-04
725     51  1325371727  2011-12-31   5  2012-01-05
717     51  1325371727  2011-12-31   6  2012-01-06
716     51  1325371727  2011-12-31   7  2012-01-07
720     51  1325371727  2011-12-31   8  2012-01-08
715     51  1325371727  2011-12-31   9  2012-01-09
726     51  1325371727  2011-12-31  10  2012-01-10
727     51  1325371727  2011-12-31  11  2012-01-11
714     51  1325371727  2011-12-31  12  2012-01-12
719     51  1325371727  2011-12-31  13  2012-01-13
975     69  1330756495  2012-03-03   0  2012-03-03
976     69  1330756495  2012-03-03   1  2012-03-04
977     69  1330756495  2012-03-03   2  2012-03-05
978     69  1330756495  2012-03-03   3  2012-03-06
979     69  1330756495  2012-03-03   4  2012-03-07
971     69  1330756495  2012-03-03   5  2012-03-08
```

Comment: I updated my answer, see if it fits your question :)

Comment: Thank you, I have done it in a slightly different way based on your answer. That is fast!

Comment: Thank you for the interesting problem and nice feedback!